# A little more tips about SignTTest

Tags: xades4j

Please could you suggest me more tips about the settings of the providers to change ?

I can see this in PKCS11KeyStoreKeyingDataProvider.java :

```
    public class PKCS11KeyStoreKeyingDataProvider extends KeyStoreKeyingDataProvider
{
    /**
     *
     * @param nativeLibraryPath the path for the native library of the specific PKCS#11 provider
     * @param providerName this string is concatenated with the prefix SunPKCS11- to produce this provider instance's name
     * @param certificateSelector the selector of signing certificate
     * @param keyStorePasswordProvider the provider of the keystore loading password (may be {@code null})
     * @param entryPasswordProvider the provider of entry passwords (may be {@code null})
     * @param returnFullChain indicates of the full certificate chain should be returned, if available
     * @throws KeyStoreException
     */
    public PKCS11KeyStoreKeyingDataProvider(
            final String nativeLibraryPath,
            final String providerName,
            SigningCertSelector certificateSelector,
            KeyStorePasswordProvider keyStorePasswordProvider,
            KeyEntryPasswordProvider entryPasswordProvider,
            boolean returnFullChain) throws KeyStoreException
    {
```

and in my SignerTTest.java :

```
PKCS11KeyStoreKeyingDataProvider ptccKeyingDataProv = new PKCS11KeyStoreKeyingDataProvider
                ("D:\\pteidpkcs11.dll", 
                "pteidpkcs11",
                new FirstCertificateSelector(), null, null, false);
```

But I don't understand, normally I download the .DLL appropriate so here the library pteidpkcs11.dll is located in D: (so in java I put "\\" : "D:"\\"pteidpkcs11.dll")

After I put the name of .dll so here pteidpkcs11 as argument.

After "new FirstCertificateSelector()" is to select the first certificate of the list of the keystore, isn't It?.

The first null is for the password of keystore provider, isn't It ?

The second null is for the password of certificate, isn't It ?

And the returnFullChain what's Its role exactly ?

And I would like to have informations about how to configure the provider because It is unclear for me for the moment during my searching.

Thanks,

William.

Answer (score 1):

> new FirstCertificateSelector() is to select the first certificate of the list of the keystore, isn't It?

Yes. You can pass in any other implementation of the `SigningCertSelector` interface.

> The first null is for the password of keystore provider, isn't It ?
>   The second null is for the password of certificate, isn't It ?

Yes. It's null because that specific PKCS#11 provider handles protection of the key stores entries (it's a smart card with a PIN).

> And the returnFullChain what's Its role exactly?

An entry in the keystore may contain a key and the associated certificate with the full certificate chain. This parameter controls if the `getSigningCertificateChain` method returns the full chain or only the leaf certificate.

The appropriate configuration and DLL will depend on which PKCS11 provider you're using. In that test I was using a a Portuguese citizen card and a smart card reader. Note that `PKCS11KeyStoreKeyingDataProvider` is just an adapter for a java key store based on sun's PKCS11 provider.